# TWIG Random Command - On Reload

Tags: php, random, twig, reload

I'm quite new to php/twig, I have been trying to use the twig 'random' command, an example is the following:

`{{ random(['apple', 'orange', 'citrus']) }} {# example output: orange #}`

It works first time when I save the file, but I'd like to work every time I reload the page; it only seems to create a new random option when I re-save the file.

Answer (score 1):

This function works right, but if the number of options is very small (like the three options of the official example) it's common to see one value again and again. Try to add more values and you'll see a different value each time.

Another issue that it might be happening is that your page is cached and therefore, you only see the first selected result until you reload your page. Twig cache doesn't affect the `random()` function, but HTTP cache or any other PHP cache may affect it.

Comment: I have tried more than three values but it continues to stay the same, only changing when I re-save the file. However, I am working on Windows currently, I just tried the same file on OSX and it works there; when I hit refresh I get a different result, ie. the word changes from 'orange' to 'apple' etc. I am using it within StaceyApp 3.0 if this is of any help.

Comment: In Windows, try to do a "hard refresh" instead of a regular browser refresh. Just hit `Ctrl + F5` and see if the value updates. If the code works on OS  X and not on Windows, I'm pretty sure it's a cache issue.

Comment: I've managed to get it working following your advice regarding cache, using `bypass_cache: true` I can now get it to work when I hit `Ctrl + F5` but would like it to work on a standard refresh as well. Anything more I can do?

Comment: The first level cache is the Twig cache itself. This doesn't affect this issue because Twig takes the `random()` function into account. The second level cache is the one your application may use. This is beyond Twig control and should be disabled for this feature to work. The third level cache is the HTTP cache that caches the entire page or parts of it. In a Symfony application, this HTTP cache is so advanced that you can cache the entire page except for small parts of it. That's what you need to maintain the app performance and the randomness of your page.

Comment: So if I include this piece of code in my application cache config file `<?php
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
?>` It works, but this is site wide, is it possible with Twig to write this so its is page specific, ie. include it in the head of the page I don't want to cache, instead of not caching the entire site?